# Xdebug not working with PhpStorm for me, but others it will work and when I attempt to start it, someone else's PhpStorm breakpoint is hit

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a strange situation where everyone is capable of running Xdebug on their PhpStorm system, except me. My settings are set up the exact same way, but when I go to check the php.ini (in PhpStorm) it shows remote enable is off. I do not have access to the php.ini file on the server however. It doesn't make sense, though because my manager's setting is turned on.

The company uses a shared server box where we log into the one development server for every dev using a URL such as `firstName_lastName.companyName.com`.

The strangest part my manager found when trying to troubleshoot this is when I turned on Xdebug in my browser and refreshed the page, his code was stopped. Are there any recommendations on settings I can set/check from my end (not having to get the CTO involved in something others are able to use already)?

I have tried for a couple of days now searching for a problem close to this, but have only been able to find things related to Xdebug not working and the solution generally means having access to the php.ini file. Also, I have yet to find a solution to the issue that my manager's code is stopped at a breakpoint instead of mine (and it might be someone else's as well since we all share the same install and it doesn't happen to him every time). If I've not described the situation well enough, I'm happy to answer any questions.

I'm trying to get this fixed on my own since the result after a few hours of working with my manager was that Xdebug is not required to fix bugs. I understand it's not, and there are some other methods that I think take a while longer, but am really hoping I can find a solution to this. Below are the settings that I have seen mentioned in other places and what mine are set to:

---

**Xdebug setting in Chrome**

IDE Key: PHPSTORM

**PhpStorm Settings**

**PHP**

PHP Language Level: 7.1

**PHP > CLI Interpreter settings > General**

Xdebug version: 2.9.6

PHP Version: 7.3.29

PHP Executable > Information window: (right now, I can't get this window to open because we are on us-west-2 in AWS, but will update this when I can connect)

**PHP > Debug > Xdebug**

Xdebug Debug port: 9000,9003

Can accept external connections: checked

I might be missing some settings in here, so please don't hesitate to ask and I'll provide them.

---

A few other things to note:

1. I have to VPN from my home; from the office there is no need to VPN. However, the IP address has been whitelisted to allow us to SSH in. I'm not able to get Xdebug to work from either location.
2. This has never worked for me, but I have only had this environment set up for about a week. Others who went through the process of setting up their dev environment with our manager are not having this issue.
3. I can't validate the debugger configuration on the web server because something is set up to allow us to use and underscore in the URL. There is an error when I try to run it, that the underscore is not allowed. We use it in our name when going to our dev server.
4. Right now AWS is having issues again, so I will need to update this post to include a few more details once that is resolved.

Comment: In general: 1) Its Xdebug that connects to the IDE and not other way around (saying just in case). Xdebug has `xdebug.remote_host` where you specify the IP address to connect to (unless it is configured to detect your IP from the browser headers). 3) The above 2 points show that if you have multiple devs debugging PHP on the same server at the same time, then you would need DBGp Proxy where you connect to the proxy and Xdebug connects to the Proxy .. and then Proxy knows which request goes where. Have a look: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/multiuser-debugging-via-xdebug-proxies.html

Comment: That's all I can say on this. Except -- You have PHP 7.3 -- consider upgrading Xdebug to v3 (3.1.1 is the latest). It has a bit easier config, less impact (slowdown) on running the code etc. Config params are different for v3, so have a look at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide after the upgrade.

Comment: 1. What you see in the .ini file in PhpStorm is irrelevant because it's an .ini file for CLI, not for web. You don't even have to have a PHP interpreter configured in PhpStorm to debug web apps 2. The strangest thing is probably caused by your manager setting `xdebug.remote_host` to his own IP. You either need `xdebug.remote_connect_back` (in case it works for you, sometimes it does) or a DBGp proxy to be able to debug on the same server at the same time 3. This is a support request rather than a SO question, really. Please contact us, PhpStorm support, via `Help | Contact Support`

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Thanks for the information. My manager doesn't have access to the server. The CTO and a few other E-level employees are the ones allowed into the configuration of the server. That being said, I will take a look at what my manager may have set and what mine needs to be for the IP.

Obviously not knowing how Xdebug and the IDE connect, I may be misunderstanding some terms and concepts. I apologize.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the recommendations. Upgrading Xdebug to v3 would require access to the server which is something my manager and I do not have, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: The answer to this question is likely going to take a lot of back and forth, with requiring information about your set-up and systems, and from what I understand from your lengthy text, that's not going to be forthcoming.